# using robolectric my expectedIntent is null when it shouldn't be

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, robolectric

I have this Activity:

```
public class WelcomeActivity extends ActivityBase {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        setContentView(R.layout.welcome);

        final OnClickListener Click = new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(WelcomeActivity.this, WelcomeDoneActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);  

                setResult(RESULT_OK);
                finish();
            }
        };
        ((TitleBar)findViewById(R.id.theTitleBar)).setOnClickCloseListener(Click);

    }
```

And this test:

```
@Test
public void clickingLogin_shouldStartLoginActivity() {
    WelcomeActivity activity = Robolectric.setupActivity(WelcomeActivity.class);
    activity.findViewById(R.id.theTitleBar).performClick();

    Intent expectedIntent = new Intent(activity, WelcomeDoneActivity.class);
    assertThat(shadowOf(activity).getNextStartedActivity(), equalTo(expectedIntent));
}
```

how come I get an assertion error?

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: <Intent { cmp=com.w/.profile.WelcomeDoneActivity }>
     but: was null
```

**Update**

I have tried this as well but the `startedIntent == null`

```
        ShadowActivity shadowActivity = shadowOf(activity);
        Intent startedIntent = shadowActivity.getNextStartedActivity();
//        ShadowIntent shadowIntent = shadowOf(startedIntent);
//        String name = startedIntent.getIntentClass().getName();
//        assertThat(shadowIntent.getIntentClass().getName(), equalTo(targetActivityName));
```

Comment: You're getting the intent of the existing activity that's calling the new activity, not the new activity with your intent. You'll need to get the new activity and pull out that intent.

Comment: how would you do this? I updated my q with new code, that doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
shadowOf(activity).getNextStartedActivity()
```

To:

```
shadowOf(activity).getNextStartedActivityForResult()
```

Comment: I get `nextStartedActivityForResult==null` for `        ShadowActivity.IntentForResult nextStartedActivityForResult = shadowOf(activity).getNextStartedActivityForResult();`

Comment: how would you assert it?

Comment: So it doesn't work. Are you sure your listener code is invoked?

Comment: I can add a log, but this should be working no? `  activity.findViewById(R.id.theTitleBar).performClick();`

Comment: Should be unless it is  removed somewhere

Answer (score 0):

In the code you posted, you are setting the onClick on the TitleBar via `setOnClickCloseListener`.
It looks like your `TitleBar` is a custom view, and the `setOnClickCloseListener` to me *implies there is a 'close' button or view on the TitleBar that performClick() should be called on, not the TitleBar itself, in order for Robolectric to behave the way you expect.*

It's hard to tell without knowing the `TitleBar` and `setOnClickCloseListener` implementation, but:

**1) If you just want to click the TitleBar to launch the new activity**, 
then change `setOnClickCloseListener` to `setOnClickListener`,

**Or**

2) **If the TitleBar contains a view of the close button/view (or whatever "ClickClose" refers to in `setOnClickCloseListener`!)**, delve into the TitleBar layout to find the ID of this view, and call performClick on that, it should resolve your issue.